# git tag: fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref

Tags: git

I am cloning a single branch from a repository and creating a tag in a python script. The commands are as follows.

```
git clone -b master --single-branch <repository adress>

git tag -a testag -m 'test'
```

It clones successfully but when it comes to adding the tag, it breaks with the following error:

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
```

Comment: What does `git status` say after your clone?

Comment: # On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: What does `cat .git/HEAD` say after the clone?

Comment: ref: refs/heads/master

Comment: `cat .git/refs/heads/master` should return a sha1 of a commit. Can you check if that commit exists?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue. You have to commit first before tagging

```
git commit
```

because you put tags on commits. So when there is no commit (like in your situation), you can't create a tag.

Answer (score 26):

I ran into the same issue and was able to fix it by changing from

```
git tag -a testtag -m 'test'
```

to

```
git tag -a testtag -m "test"
```

I was running in Windows 7.
Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Using Cmder on W10, this is what actually helped.

Answer (score 8):

I also faced `git tag: fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref` issue when I was missing -m in the following command.(during tag creation)

```
git tag -a testtag 'test'
```

changing to

```
git tag -a testtag -m 'test'
```

fixed the issue

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I cloned from a bare repo and tried to use 'git tag' in that cloned repo, and that is where I was getting the error. To fix it I had to at least one push up to master before I could begin tagging. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the remote repository

```
cd /path/to/remote/repository
git config --bool core.bare true
```

Comment: What does that do precisely?

Comment: According to this page http://bitflop.com/document/111

"A "bare" repository in Git just contains the version control information and no working files (no tree) and it doesn't contain the special .git sub-directory. Instead, it contains all the contents of the .git sub-directory directly in the main directory itself."