# fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting `fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref.` whenever I try to commit.

I have tried

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

but it's not working

Also tried

```
git commit
```

it's not working either from below the sources.

[Git 'fatal: No such ref: HEAD'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848607/git-fatal-no-such-ref-head)

[git tag: fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116545/git-tag-fatal-failed-to-resolve-head-as-a-valid-ref)

Please help. All my commit history is also gone.

Comment: what is the output of `git branch -v` ?

Comment: hi @Flows its giving same "fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref."
if I try git log then its giving me fatal: your current branch appears to be broken

Comment: Looking around internet, I found it may be due to permission access. Could you give 777 permissions to the `.git` folder recursively ?

Comment: I think 777 command is for remote directory? My problem is locally...getting this error when I do commit....

Comment: I know the problem is usually on remote repository but you can try that in your local repository too.

Comment: ok,can you give me cmd to do it please?

Comment: Assuming you can use command line, be sure to have root permission, or connect with sudo user. Move to your git repository (`cd`) and type `sudo chmod 777 -R .git`.

Comment: did, doesn't seems like problem got solved

Comment: Argh I am sorry, I don't have ideas for now

Comment: thanks for trying to help though :)

Answer (score 76):

I have also encountered the same issue, and have resolved it as follows:

1. Clone your same project in some other folder.
2. Copy the (hidden) `.git` folder of the cloned project.
3. Finally replace the `.git` folder of the original project with the one that you've have copied.

##### Edit

**Why does this happen?**

- Broken git repositories are often the result of file system corruption due to abrupt power failure or other abnormalities.
- Since git stores all the information inside `.git` folder and if they are corrupted git can no longer recognize the repository.

**Caveats**

Everything in your previous `.git` folder will be gone. Configurations like *remote reference name(s)* must be set up again.

Comment: This actually worked for me too, I had a repo that randomly could no longer find any branches (not even master), but nothing else I did (git checkout master, git checkout -, etc) worked. A solution as simple as recloning and then copying the git folder fixed it. This even let me keep my changes, so I didn't need to redo them.

Comment: where can I find the .git folder?

Comment: @Andrea: Go to to your application directory and type `ls -a`. you'll find one.

Comment: @PraveshKhatri are you cloning from origin?

Comment: Is there any risk of losing files/changes using this approach?

Comment: @Jacques, yes it’s cloned from origin, and yes there is a risk. If you have commits that are not pushed or you have stash, you’ll not get again there. But if you have made current changes, you’ll be able to get them as diff.

Answer (score 12):

I got this issue due a disk failure. I know this is an old question but maybe it can help someone. In my case I had a local branch where I was working on before my repo got corrupted so re-cloning the repo was not suitable for me. Any answer here or in other post helped me, except this little piece of code I found [here](https://www.it-swarm.dev/de/git/git-toedlich-keine-solche-ref-head/972058959/). I just ran this command in the root of my repo:

```
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

After that, I was able to excecute, `git branch`, `git commit` and all other git commands.

I hope this can help someone!

Comment: Sorry to say, but this issue actually made issues worse for me, now I see: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: my guy you deserve an upvote

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had the same issue where my system, unfortunately, crashed when I tried to save changes in one of the files on my working branch. Also, I had 10s of other WIP branches which I didn't want to lose. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

My problem was with

```
git init
git add .
```

Tried

```
git reset
  fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
git reset --hard
  fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref.
```

**Solved with**

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Enviroment

> git version 1.7.5.4
>
> Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem after a *Blue Screen of Death* incident - so it was similar to what Sudip Bhandari said above.

- I looked in `.git/refs/heads/<mybranch>` and found that the entry was corrupted (illegible). This file is supposed to contain the full commit-id of the HEAD branch.
- I cloned a new repository and copied `.git/refs/heads/<mybranch>` from the new checkout over the corrupted one (I guess I could've just repaired it by pasting in a recent commit-id from stash or whatever).
- back in the original repository, I did `git rm -r --cached .` and `git reset --hard` to clean up and then found all was back to normal again.

Comment: I just did the second step above and all was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I ended up with **two branches with the same name** after a branch renaming. By removing one of them in *.git/refs/heads* it all went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the files under .git/refs/heads. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Backup your existing .git folder.
2. Clone your project from git repository into new folder.
3. Copy .git from new project folder and replace your original .git folder.

Answer (score 0):

WHY - **fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref**?

git is not able to figure out the reference and you may see this issue if the reference head is corrupted.

Suppose originally you checked out a feature branch out of the master branch and because of some failure you hit this issue. You can check the ref of the header file it should be **corrupted or no value** in it. Ideally, this file supposes to keep the **commit hash value**.

```
cat .git/refs/heads/<my-branch>
```

SOLUTION - Replacing the corrupted ref or ref value will solve the problem.

Goto `.git/ref/heads/` and check if you already have some branch there and copy the commit hash value to your branch.

```
cat .git/refs/heads/<branch_with_commit_details> > .git/refs/heads/<my-branch>
```

OR you can clone the source code in another directory and copy the same hash value to `my-branch`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just needed to do a git push in the main folder. I used git bash for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with submodules and did not commit my changes yet.
After commit, it starts to behave normal.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution for those who don't want to work on a new folder or clone again, just delete the .git folder, for windows users it may not show in the file explorer and deleting from cmd may be a problem, i dont know how to go about that. For me i use WSL so i can just switch between linux and windows. Type `rm -fr .git` to delete it. then start out like a new git repo with git init, git remote add origin, git branch -m (to what it was), git add ., git commit, git push origin branchName --force (it will raise an error if you don't force) then you will be back to speed

Answer (score -1):

Solution which preserves your Git history and local changes.

- delete your .git folder
- open command line
- `git init`
- `git add origin [REMOTE_REPOSITORY_URL]`
- `git origin fetch`
- `git reset --soft origin/[BRANCH_NAME]` -> this forces your local branch to be exactly like the remote branch *except* it will *not* overwrite your currently uncommitted changes.
- `git add .`
- Check results with `git status`

Answer (score -3):

The best solution for this problem:

'**fatal: Failed to resolve HEAD as a valid ref**'

1. Open the project on Eclipse IDE
2. Goto project Team menu and select Switch to, finally you can switch 
   your current detached branch to your choice now.

As attached screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: The user didn't mention Eclipse.