# git tag: fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/my_tag_name' as a valid ref

Tags: git, svn, tags, bitbucket, git-svn

I'm currently cloning a svn repo that has standard layout. It currently contains the code corresponding one iOS app and one Android app. Tags indicates when we  froze the code and released it.

I cloned the repo using (the SVN server runs locally on the machine) :

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk --tags=/tags --branches=/branches --authors-file=authors.txt http://localhost/svn/MY_PROJECT MY_PROJECT
```

Then in MY_PROJECT,

```
git remote add origin ssh://git@my_bitbuket_repo.com:7999/test/MY_PROJECT.git
git push -u origin master
```

And now, the problematic part. Now I wan't to push the tags.

```
mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT (master)
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/tags/android_v1.4.2
  remotes/tags/android_v1.5
  remotes/tags/iOS-1.4.1
  remotes/tags/iOS-1.5
  remotes/tags/iOS_Android_1.3
  remotes/tags/ios_v1.6
  remotes/trunk
```

So I run the script given [on this useful page](http://www.sailmaker.co.uk/blog/2013/05/05/migrating-from-svn-to-git-preserving-branches-and-tags-3/#convert-tags), and here is what I get :

```
mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT (master)
$ sh convert_remotes_to_tags.sh
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/android_v1.4.2' as a valid ref.
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/android_v1.5' as a valid ref.
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/iOS-1.4.1' as a valid ref.
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/iOS-1.5' as a valid ref.
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/iOS_Android_1.3' as a valid ref.
```

So I tested what is given [on this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217914/3801887) :

```
mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT (master)
$ cd .git/svn/refs/remotes/tags/android_v1.4.2/

mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT/.git/svn/refs/remotes/tags/android_v1.4.2 (GIT_DIR!)
$ git config --bool core.bare true
```

and

```
mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT (master)
$ cd .git/svn/refs/remotes/tags/

mylogin@MY_MACHINE MINGW64 ~/workspace/svn2git/MY_PROJECT/.git/svn/refs/remotes/tags (BARE:master)
$ git config --bool core.bare true
```

But this won't work either (running the same convert-tags-script)...

I tested another script to migrate the tags, here it is :

```
for tag in `git branch -r --sort=committerdate | grep "tags/" | sed 's/.*tags\///'`; do
  git fetch --tags # must fetch tags before pushing more
  git tag -a -m "Convert Subversion tag" $tag refs/remotes/origin/tags/$tag
  git push origin $tag
done
```

But this won't work as well, having such logs :

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/android_v1.4.1' as a valid ref.
error: src refspec android_v1.4.1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my_bitbuket_repo.com:7999/df/my_project.git'
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/iOS-1.4' as a valid ref.
error: src refspec iOS-1.4 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my_bitbuket_repo.com:7999/df/my_project.git'
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/android_v1.4.2' as a valid ref.
error: src refspec android_v1.4.2 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my_bitbuket_repo.com:7999/df/my_project.git'
fatal: Failed to resolve 'refs/remotes/origin/tags/iOS-1.4.1' as a valid ref.
error: src refspec iOS-1.4.1 does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@my_bitbuket_repo.com:7999/df/my_project.git'
```

**Do you have any clue about how to migrate those tags ?**

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion and you are using only Git afterwards or do you want to commit back to SVN from the Git clone?

Comment: It is a one-time conversion. I want to go to Bitbucket and I don't plan to come back to SVN.

Comment: I used SmartGit http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/ to migrate the repo and it gathered the tags correctly.

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case and also makes proper Git tags from the SVN tags.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the wrong `svn2git` in your case) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: Thank you for you comment @Vampire. I will use it if I have a linux machine under hand. Presently I only have a Windows one...

Comment: But how are you able to run qmake && make directly on a windows machine ?

Comment: Well, either you install Cygwin and make in there, or you install the Qt SDK and do it. Where is the problem? Qt is made for cross-platform projects.