# How to resolve 'Head' as a valid reference?

Tags: gitbucket

I am trying to sign my git tag, but I get an error. and then if I do commit -m it tells me "nothing added to commit but untracked files present."

Comment: We need more details: what you are trying to do, which commands did you run, do you use some guide? "nothing added to commit" means you did not added any files to commit stage in git. Did you had any experience with git? (e.g. try this guide http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Comment: I am following this guide 
https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Signing-Your-Work, to test it out. I got to this part: git tag -s v1.5 -m 'my signed 1.5 tag' after that I just get an error. 'Fatal: fail to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref' . Also I am new to gitbucket.

Comment: Have you commited already to this repo? Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116545/git-tag-fatal-failed-to-resolve-head-as-a-valid-ref

Comment: I did git commit and it sends a message "On Branch Master ... Initial Commit... Untracked Files: HEAD, config.. nothing added to commit but untracked files present".. I am not entirely sure if I am missing a step here.

Comment: Does simple tagging (git tag -a ...) works? If it shows the same error, look for answers in the question that I linked above. Yours may be a duplicate.

Comment: When I run a simple tagging, it just gives me the list of usage. I will look more in the link you send. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git tag: fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116545/git-tag-fatal-failed-to-resolve-head-as-a-valid-ref)